# Storing Sprite Kit Level Data

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

There is a project I am working on in which a set of targets appear onto the screen. The targets should appear a certain amount at the same time, and with a certain delay in between each appearance. My question is how I would correctly store the level data for this game. I was considering using a csv file to store the level data (target type, location, delay, etc.), but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it. I had also considered making a level object to store level information, but I'm not sure. Apple says to use 'Archives of sprite nodes', but I can't seem to find out what that means. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you think about using a plist file instead? That would be the easiest to parse. You could have an array of targets (dictionarys) and then define position, absolute delay and what ever else you want.

[image]

Then just read it into an array:

```
NSArray *targets = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in targets) {
    CGPoint position = CGPointMake([dictionary[@"positionX"] floatValue], 
                                   [dictionary[@"positionY"] floatValue]);
    float delay = [dictionary[@"time"] floatValue];
    // Do something with this information, maybe create a Target instance etc.
}
```

You could also do the same with CSV files, but they would be a little bit more difficult to parse (not too difficult though).

Regarding archives, what Apple means is that all Sprite Kit classes support NSCoding. That means they can be archived into a file (or NSData object) and later unarchived from that archive. This is however different from what you want to do. Archiving would create a single "snapshot" of the current state of the game. So this would be nice to save the game for instance when the user leaves.

Comment: So there would be no need for a Level object?

Comment: Just a question, when

Comment: Hi @DrummerB, thank you for your answer. I just posted a question about how to store and load tile maps in Swift. I'm not sure if that can be done with a plist file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022374/how-to-edit-and-load-tile-maps-in-swift Please take a look!