# How to edit and load tile maps in Swift?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm working in a side-scroller with Sprite Kit. I want to create different levels, however I don't know how to edit, save and load the level maps.

I found a good answer about how to store information about a level in a plist file. [Storing Sprite Kit Level Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501629/storing-sprite-kit-level-data) I think it shouldn't be very hard to save all nodes on a plist file and load them. However I would still have to build my own leven editor and I'm not sure if I want to do that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Any info you can find about using tile maps with SpriteKit (such as the questions you see in the Related sidebar on this very page) apply equally well to ObjC and Swift.

Comment: I read a bit today about .tmx maps I understand it's a filetype for an application called tiled. But idk, is it the most common format or what? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: There's no real alternative to Tiled for iOS devs. Though the TMX format is understood by a few iPad tilemap editing apps but they don't have nearly all the features of desktop Tiled and often don't support hex, staggered iso and sometimes not even regular iso maps. For a list of alternative tilemap editors see the Resources section on TilemapKit: http://tilemapkit.com/tilemapkit-documentation/#Resources_for_Tilemap_Development